# How to bind a jetty server to specific set of IPs.

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

How to bind a jetty server to multiple IPs. In my case I want request coming on 172.18.1.1 to 172.18.1.5 ips binded on same port will get handle by a single instance of server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting up a proxy server on all the IPs which just forwards the requests to your instance.

Comment: No,this is not a option for me.I cannot play with the machine settings.Only option I have is to do somehow by coding.I am wondering is there something like virtualhost.